# How to redirect a URL that has parentheses

Tags: linux, apache

I have URLs like the following, which have parentheses() in their syntax. These URLs will redirect to different links. How do I handle parentheses() in my URL redirections?

```
^/test1/mkt_iboxx_usd_liquid_investment_grade_(ttm_hedged)_index.pdf
^/test/mkt_iboxx_usd_liquid_high_yield_(ttm%20jpy%20hedged)_index_guide.pdf
```

I am not sure how to handle it. I tried to search but did not find anything good.

Answer (score -1):

You're going to need to do the following to get your redirects to work:

- For the parentheses, you just need to escape them. Use `\(` instead of `(`.
- The URLs cannot begin with a leading slash because Apache is weird.
- Use `\s` instead of `%20`. `\s` is the regex character for empty whitespace.

Your redirects would then look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test1/mkt_iboxx_usd_liquid_investment_grade_\(ttm_hedged\)_index.pdf http://localhost/test [R=302]
RewriteRule ^test/mkt_iboxx_usd_liquid_high_yield_\(ttm\sjpy\shedged\)_index_guide.pdf http://localhost/test [R=302]
```

Comment: I appreciate you take time to comment. I will try and let you know.